# How to force gettext to translate a specific language, independently from current language?

Tags: php, translation, gettext

How can i tell the function [gettext()](https://www.php.net/gettext)  to translate a word to a specific language independently from the language currently set?

Let's take an example

Let us assume the default language is english.
Let's take the word *tree*. In italian it will be *albero*.

If i am browsing the english version of my website, all the content of the page will be translated in english. In particular, if i have in my php code the line `echo _('tree');`, *tree* will be outputted.

What i would love to accomplish is to output *albero* when i'm browsing the english version of the website. I would love to tell _() to translate only that specific word in that specific part of the page in italian, even if the current language is in english. In my head it's something like `_('tree', 'it_IT')` where it_IT tells the gettext to ignore the English language and override it with with Italian only for that call.

Is it possible to do that with gettext()?
If yes, how? If no, any other solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, GNU `gettext` does not support this.

You can fake it by temporarily changing your locale:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
echo _('tree');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
```

Comment: I can't really understand how to use it...Here is a pastebin of my implementation http://pastebin.com/7zpT7HRq . Can you help me with that? In PHP manual, i see no difference between `bindtextdomain("module1", "//path/to/my/locale/folder");` and `bindtextdomain("module2", "//path/to/my/locale/folder");`...the `locale` folder is the same for english and italian! In fact, english and italian are subfolders of `locale`, so each bindtextdomain will point to the same folder...

Comment: @AlbertoFontana, my mistake. It appears that you cannot do this using `gettext`. You may have to use `putenv` and `setlocale` to switch temporarily into Italian. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, i made it by doing `setlocale(LC_ALL, "it_IT");` and then `echo _('tree');` and then `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");`!

Comment: Instead of changing the locale, which also affects other aspects of the environment and needs the locale to be installed, you can use the environment variable `LANGUAGE`.